# Can Erlang interface to Go like it does with C (e.g. NIF)?

Tags: erlang, erlang-nif

I have a C NIF in my Erlang project that has limitations, due to libraries that it relies on (unstable libraries, or libraries that I need that don't exist).  I think that I can do what I want to do, in Go.  Can Erlang interface to Go like this?

Comment: I suppose no. But you can look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910212/erlang-interfacing-with-xalan-port-driver-or-nif/2915090#2915090) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817331/converting-erlang-c-port-example-to-erlang-golang).

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you could look into [Go-node](https://github.com/goerlang/node). It uses standard Erlang distributed messaging.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the above comments into an answer:

1. There is no such thing as a simple Go NIF
2. The standard Erlang approach to needing to make foreign calls of moderate weight is to write a port driver. [There's an example of calling Go from Erlang in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34947048/1220269).
3. A more heavyweight solution is to implement the distribution interface and make a whole foreign node. [There's some code to do this that might be interesting](https://github.com/goerlang/node).
4. If you really wanted to make a Go NIF, you'd want to write a C interface to Go, then call that C interface as your NIF.